# BMP280 pressure as a DC motor switch - issues

Tags: arduino-uno, i2c

I'm attempting to control a DC vacuum pump to turn off when it hits a BMP-280 reads a set pressure lower than when it spins up (guesstimate pressure, I've got it hooked up to tweak in person). Everything works fine for pressure until I get to the `runPump()` subroutine, when the pressure callouts go from pascal to very large odd numbers.  I've tried variations of INT/FLOAT/LONG but I still either get a 0 pascal reading or an OVF. The BMP later in runPump does return pressure in pascal.

```cpp
#include <Wire.h>    //This library allows you to communicate with I2C devices (BMP280)
#include "i2c.h"     //same
#include "i2c_BMP280.h"   //same
BMP280 bmp280;
int inches = 0;
int motorPin2 = 10;
int motorPin1 = 9;
int triggerPin = 7;  // For ultrasonic sensor
int echoPin = 4;    // For Ultrasonic sensor
long duration;
long distance;


void setup() {

  pinMode(triggerPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(motorPin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motorPin2, OUTPUT);

  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.print("Probe BMP280: ");
  if (bmp280.initialize()) Serial.println("Sensor found");
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Sensor missing");
    while (1) {}
  }

  // onetime-measure:
  bmp280.setEnabled(0);
  bmp280.triggerMeasurement();
}


void trig() {
  Serial.println("Ping!");
  digitalWrite(triggerPin, LOW);
  delay(2);
  digitalWrite(triggerPin, HIGH);
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(triggerPin, LOW);
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
  inches = (duration / 2) / 74;
  Serial.print("Inches: ");
  Serial.println(inches);
  delay(250);
}

void runPump() {
  //  Serial.println("Running Pump!!!!!!");
  //  #include <Wire.h>    //This library allows you to communicate with I2C devices (BMP280)
  //  #include "i2c.h"     //same
  //  #include "i2c_BMP280.h"   //same
  //  BMP280 bmp280;
  //  int motorPin1 = 10;
  //  int motorPin2 = 9;

  bmp280.awaitMeasurement();
  float  pascal;
  bmp280.getPressure(pascal);
  bmp280.triggerMeasurement();

  float runningpressure;
  float deflatepressure;
  runningpressure = (int) pascal;
  deflatepressure = (runningpressure - 600); //pascal minus a bit
  Serial.print("Starting pressure: ");
  Serial.println(pascal);
  Serial.print("Goal pressure: ");
  Serial.println(deflatepressure);

  while (runningpressure > deflatepressure) {
    Serial.println("Engaging Vacuum Pump!!!");
    digitalWrite(motorPin1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(motorPin2, HIGH);
    delay(250);
    bmp280.awaitMeasurement();
    bmp280.getPressure(pascal);
    bmp280.triggerMeasurement();
    Serial.print("Current pressure: ");
    Serial.println(runningpressure);
    Serial.print("Goal pressure:");
    Serial.println(deflatepressure);
    Serial.print(runningpressure - deflatepressure);
    Serial.println(" more to go.....");
    delay(250);
  }
  //  else{
  Serial.println("Shutting Down!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
  digitalWrite(motorPin1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motorPin2, LOW);
  delay(2000);
  //  }
}

void loop() {

  bmp280.awaitMeasurement();
  float  pascal;
  bmp280.getPressure(pascal);
  bmp280.triggerMeasurement();
  Serial.print("Pressure: ");
  Serial.print(pascal);
  Serial.println(" Pa;");
  trig();



  if (inches > 4 && inches < 10) {
    runPump();
  } else
    digitalWrite(motorPin1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motorPin2, LOW);
  delay(5);
}


//  Serial.println("Extruding Glove!@!!!");
//  digitalWrite(motorPinR, HIGH);  //extrudes gloves
//  delay(500);                      // waits .5 seconds
//  digitalWrite(motorPinR, LOW);   // stops extruding
```

Comment: Try manually controlling the pump with it powered from a different power source. The sensor might be acting erratically due to noise caused by the DC motor. Just make a loop to read the sensor. Turn on and off the pump (powered externally) and see if you have the expected behaviour. If the readings are OK then continue looking at the software.

Comment: Rudy, thanks!  I was already running the battery from a separate source and had modified the circuit to reduce noise.  What ended up fixing it was adding a diode on the ultrasonic sensor as a diagnostic to show it was working.  It just wasn't where I was expecting noise from.

Comment: I was concerned that you would be trying to figure out what was wrong with your program when then the problem could have been a hardware issue. Normally I am telling our programmers that it isn't a hardware problem and the problem is with their code.  I'm glad you figured it out.